# Oracle PLSQL - How to query to return result if combination of columns found

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a scenario here - user need to complete either one of 2 set of 3 courses then only can pass. If he just complete 1 or 2 courses, the result will be 0. If he completes all course the return result will be 1.

must comlete CourseA, CourseB, CourseC to pass
or complete CourseD, CourseE, CourseF to pass

Comment: Post Your Question with proper sample Data and required output. It will helps people to understand question quickly.

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you can use case/when to return 1 if a given course was passed and then sum them, if the sum >=2: success

Comment: @vc74 - did you read the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a good practice problem if the base table has three columns: student_id, course_id and grade (pass/fail), and there is another table for courses, with course_id and "track" (and perhaps other information about courses). "track" means group of courses that must all be passed in order to graduate; for example, one "track" requires courses A, B, C (assuming those are course id's), and the other requires D, E, F.

Here is a prototype, with a possible solution.

```
with
     enrollments ( student_id, course_id, grade ) as (
       select 1001, 'A', 'Pass' from dual union all
       select 1001, 'B', 'Pass' from dual union all
       select 1001, 'D', 'Fail' from dual union all
       select 1001, 'E', 'Pass' from dual union all
       select 1002, 'A', 'Pass' from dual union all
       select 1002, 'C', 'Pass' from dual union all
       select 1002, 'D', 'Pass' from dual union all
       select 1003, 'F', 'Fail' from dual union all
       select 1005, 'A', 'Fail' from dual union all
       select 1005, 'D', 'Pass' from dual union all
       select 1005, 'E', 'Pass' from dual union all
       select 1005, 'F', 'Pass' from dual
     ),
     courses ( course_id, track ) as (
       select 'A', 101 from dual union all
       select 'B', 101 from dual union all
       select 'C', 101 from dual union all
       select 'D', 201 from dual union all
       select 'E', 201 from dual union all
       select 'F', 201 from dual
     )
-- >>  end of test data; the actual solution (SQL query) begins below this line  << --
select   distinct student_id
from     enrollments e join courses c on e.course_id = c.course_id
where    grade = 'Pass'
group by student_id, track
having   count(*) = 3
;

STUDENT_ID
----------
1005
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I wanted exactly. Upvoted.